# View Model IEnumerable<> property is coming back null (not binding) from post method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view model that contains a Product class type and an IEnumerable< Product > type.  On the post the first level product object comes back binded from the viewmodel whereas the product enum is coming back null.

Why is the IEnumerable< Prouduct> property not getting binded to my view model per the post?  Thx!

Models:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductIndexViewModel
{
    public Product NewProduct { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class BoringStoreContext 
{
        public BoringStoreContext()
         {
             Products = new List<Product>();
             Products.Add(new Product() { ID = 1, Name = "Sure", Price = (decimal)(1.10) });
             Products.Add(new Product() { ID = 2, Name = "Sure2", Price = (decimal)(2.10) });
         }
         public List<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
```

View:

```
@model ProductIndexViewModel

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewProduct.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewProduct.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewProduct.Price)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewProduct.Price)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
    </div>

        foreach (var item in Model.Products)
        { 
         <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.ID)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.ID)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => item.Price)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => item.Price)
    </div>

        }
       }
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    BoringStoreContext db = new BoringStoreContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ProductIndexViewModel viewModel = new ProductIndexViewModel
        {
            NewProduct = new Product(),
            Products = db.Products
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ProductIndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // ???? viewModel.Products is NULL here
        // ???? viewModel.NewProduct comes back fine

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Did you customize your EditorFor ?

Comment: @Shyju: Hi I didnt..I'm assuming that if I create an EditorTemplate for Product.cshtml I could call @HTml.EditorFor(model => model.Products) and it will probably work?

Comment: Yes you can. I added an answer with that approach.

Comment: I have the same issue. but still couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not using your lambda expression properly. You need to be accessing the Products list through the model. Try doing it like this:

```
@count = 0
foreach (var item in Model.Products)
    { 
     <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products[count].ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Products[count].ID)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products[count].Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Products[count].Name)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products[count].Price)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Products[count].Price)
</div>
@count++
    }
```

**Edit**

Controller:

```
BoringStoreContext db = new BoringStoreContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ProductIndexViewModel viewModel = new ProductIndexViewModel
        {
            NewProduct = new Product(),
            Products = db.Products
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ProductIndexViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // work with view model

        return View();
    }
```

Model

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductIndexViewModel
{
    public Product NewProduct { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class BoringStoreContext
{
    public BoringStoreContext()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
        Products.Add(new Product() { ID = 1, Name = "Sure", Price = (decimal)(1.10) });
        Products.Add(new Product() { ID = 2, Name = "Sure2", Price = (decimal)(2.10) });
    }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Models.ProductIndexViewModel


@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewProduct.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewProduct.Name)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewProduct.Price)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewProduct.Price)
</div>


for (int count = 0; count < Model.Products.Count; count++ )
{ 
    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products[count].ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Products[count].ID)
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products[count].Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Products[count].Name)
    </div>
    <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Products[count].Price)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Products[count].Price)
    </div>
}

<div>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Product" />
</div>
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a foreach loop to mimic a regular for loop? And why would you repeatedly call model.Products[count] when you already have the item in the foreach loop?

Comment: @Xander - Thank you. The Helpers don't really respond well to using the `.` expansion so `model.Products.item.ID` wont work hence the indexing. I forgot to remove the `.item` however from the solution and editted it to reflect the change you commented on in your first comment.

Comment: @rossisdead - As commented above, `model.Products.item` is not valid here as nice as it would be to use. A `for(int count = 0; count < Model.Products.Count; count++)` would also suffice.

Comment: Ah, I went and tested it out. I didn't realize that using the indexer caused the rendered name attribute to also include the index. Neat!

Comment: @TravisJ: Thx for the reply. Not sure if I'm missing something here but even after correcting the [count] (can't use [] indexing on IEnumerables to model.Products.ElementAt(count).ID (etc...) the product list still comes back as null in the view model.

Comment: @JaJ try removing the extra `@` sign in the view markup ... `@using (@Html.BeginForm())`

Comment: @JaJ - Actually you are correct, this should be held in a List, see edit for a completed, testing, working, example. Note the change from `IEnumerable` to `List`, and the `for(){}` loop change.

Comment: Oops, previous comment should read ..., tested, ... because I actually ran that code and in the debugger the viewmodel did hold the list of products.

Comment: @TravisJ: Awesome! Tested and works! So, in a nutshell my original wasn't working because I wasn't accessing the model correctly?  I mean via item.ID, etc,. per foreach (var item in ViewModel.Prodcuts) is not referencing the model correctly?

Comment: @JaJ - Well, in the lambda expression, when you start with `model =>` you have to access that in the next part. MSDN: "The lambda expression x => x * x is read "x goes to x times x." So you would need to use that model in the second half of the expression if you wanted the binding. As for using the `foreach` with a dot notation for access, this is, in my opinion, a missing feature that badly needs implementation from the MVC/Razor team.

Comment: @TravisJ: Makes sense. Agreed with your last comment!  Thx again!

Comment: Nice!  Good work folks.   My issue is simple and it kicks my a$$ everytime.  foreach (var item in Model) needs to know what to access from the viewmodel  @foreach (var item in Model.Products)

Answer (score 7):

[Travis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9915477/282110) will address the issue. Here is another approach using EditorTemplates

You can use an `Editor template` to display the Products and it will work fine.

**1)** Create a Folder called "EditorTemplates" under your Views/Home folder

**2 )** Add a view called "`Products`" inside that.
Add this code to that view

```
@model SO_MVC.Models.Product
@{
   Layout = null;
}
<p>
  @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.ID)
  @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.ID) 
</p>
<p>
  @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Name)
  @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Name)
</p>
<p>
  @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Price)
  @Html.EditorFor(x=>x.Price)
</p> 
@Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)
```

and in your Main View, you can call this Editor template like this

```
  @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Products)
```